# How can make two nested loops?

Tags: prolog

how you can make two nested loops?

I would like for example to perform two nested loops that execute all possible sums of the elements of a list and comparing the result with the elements of another list.

for example

to the question:

```
? - Total_sum ([2,34,3,21,4,7,9], [10,3,6], Result, L).
```

I would like the answer:

```
Result = [[3,7], [2,4]].
L = [34,21,9].
```

I able to perform only simple verification.
but I not able to run nested loops.

The code is as follows:

```
total_sum([],_,[],[]).

total_sum(_,[],[],[]).

total_sum([A,B|L],[X|Y],Result,L2):-
    X is A + B,
    R = [A,B],
    total_sum(L,Y,Res,L2),
    append([R],Res,Result).

total_sum([A,C|L],[X|Y],Result,C2):-
    total_sum([A|L],[X|Y],Result,C1),
    append([C],C1,C2).
```

can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: By "all possible sums of the elements of a list" do you really mean "all possible sums of *pairs of elements* of a list"?

Answer (score 2):

this snippet *could* satisfy your requirements

```
total_sum(Available, ToMatch, [[N,M]|PairsSatisfing], Remains) :-
    select(N, Available, A1),
    select(M, A1, Rest),
    X is N + M,
    memberchk(X, ToMatch),
    !, total_sum(Rest, ToMatch, PairsSatisfing, Remains).
total_sum(Rest, _ToMatch, [], Rest).
```

yields

```
?- total_sum([2,34,3,21,4,7,9], [10,3,6], Result, L).
Result = [[2, 4], [3, 7]],
L = [34, 21, 9].
```

You could need to reverse the `PairsSatisfing` list.

I hope the variables' names are descriptive of the intent. Note that the specification is a bit ambiguous, as there could be much more pairs satisfying the relation. Remove the cut before the recursive call to see all of them...

If an element in `ToMatch` can be 'used' only once, use

```
...
select(X, ToMatch, ToMatchRem),
!, total_sum(Rest, ToMatchRem, PairsSatisfing, Remains).
```

This will also remove a bit of ambiguity...